# Typescript - how do you deal with common properties between two interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, clone

I have an interfaceA1 and interfaceB with some properties in common

```
interface A1 {
  id : string,
  version: number,
  data: userData,
  createdBy: string
}

interface userData {
  data: string,
  status: string
}

interface B {
  id : string,
  version: number,
  definition : JSON
}
```

So, there are some properties like id, version is common between interfaceA1 and interfaceB

I have variable of type interfaceA with following values

```
let interfaceA1Data: interfaceA1 = {
  id : '123abc',
  version: 1,
  data: {
    data: 'value',
    status: 'value'
  },
  createdBy: 'me'
}
```

I have another variable of type interfaceB, that is just declared

```
let interfaceBData: interfaceB
```

Now I want to copy the values of common properties from interfaceA1Data to interfaceBData. The non-common properties should be added to the definition property. So, in the end the interfaceBData will hold the following values.

```
interfaceBData = {
  id : '123abc',
  version: 1,
  definition: {
    data: {
      data: 'value',
      status: 'value'
    },
    createdBy: 'me'
  }
}
```

How to achieve this in typescript?

The transformer should be generic say if I have an interfaceA2, how to convert to interfaceB type. In all the case destination interface is same only the source interface differs.

```
interface A2 {
  id : string,
  version: number,
  value: valueType,
  createdBy: string
}

interface valueType {
  type: string,
  requester: string
}
```

Comment: "attribute" is the wrong term. TypeScript+JavaScript isn't Python: object members are called "properties".

Comment: TypeScript works on the basis of _type-erasure_ (types aren't reified at runtime), so TypeScript cannot filter properties for you by itself - you'll need to copy values over manually - though you can reduce your workload with judicious application of `Object.assign`.

Comment: Hi, Can i get some starter code of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If there's an intentional overlap between two interfaces, it might be worth extracting common properties into a separate interface. For example:

```
interface Versioned {
  id: string,
  version: number
}

interface userData {
  data: string,
  status: string
}

interface valueType {
  type: string,
  requester: string
}

interface A1 extends Versioned {
  data: userData,
  createdBy: string
}

interface A2 extends Versioned {
  value: valueType,
  createdBy: string
}
```

Now, you can either proceed with creating 'B' interface the same way you did before, just by extending Versioned once more with `definition` property as Object:

```
interface B extends Versioned {
  definition: Object
}
```

... but you might want to provide additional strictness by turning it into generic interface instead, like this:

```
interface Serialized<T extends Versioned> extends Versioned {
  definition: Omit<T, keyof Versioned>
}
```

Now you can easily write a transformer function for any type/interface extending Versioned turning this into specific shape of Serialized:

```
function transformer<T extends Versioned>(
{id, version, ...args}: T): Serialized<T> {
  return {
    id, version,
    definition: {...args}
  }
}
```

Here's [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGrQM7APYggE2QG8BYAKGWWHwC5kMwpQBzAGnMoDdMcQ6QArgFsARtHIBfcuVCRYiFAGVowOABtgALwIAeACrIIAD0gh8GND1wEAfIZMQzF9FCzXCpCsnwQYoYGC8dADyQgH6rMgA1hAAntgwlq68tpLSZLLQ8EjIAIL2puZJbngeHN5wYHB0AhjQACKVcOxeCFAQlQQAQrF0DEwgzGkZ4FkKyLUNTcTl%20E19jCwtlAyVtQsDQ2RSZDKj8jm5AEwFjkUuJQQzXpzqAhB0t2r3erEADhDLyG0dkPg9GxYw0yBxQTxe7xQnkoYEhgMGX3aAEd7gxoPCtjtyDABCAEIFcMhGHAQBgYNgoEJoPpTk5iil8DYABREaiRbjJXCRAB0vLgUGYGAkdD0AEo6MomOotLo9HZoZRFe0wAIoCBrorNVR8OyrCAvlrvL5-AS%20MRedz%20YKdoabYqsWQ1BAwFR9tkILlGlU6PkALwa7XIOgAcgAjEcAMxwEQIYNfDklOihr5zb0Byip6rIYPgiChuPlFZVFUYEO5-PlCRfH6df69bNUgvbdJOl0g91dL1ZyWqDTafA6XJ2f3E0nkynQJnthSepqigDc5AQuAw2Cd3LU2GYU7dCk7c8Xu0dztdcndxy7PpO-oV1CD2fDUZjTa4eqT8buD3TRLh2dzRxfJUIBRCA0SgMtPwAytq3aWsAQbCAmwdVtTzGJAuiOS9kB7aV%200HI5hyJKASTJCkqSgHczxnTCDyXFc1wgDct0otCIAwrsFyAA).

Comment: Hi, the transformer logic you mentioned is specific to the interface. I have edited my question now, can you check how to achieve now?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This works with both A and A2 as long as expected output format is the same.

Comment: Yes, expected output format is same, whatever the non-common attributes of source interface will go into the definition of interfaceB

Comment: How should definition of interfaceB look like if you want to be unified (it's a single interface) yet flexible enough to support both 'input' interfaces? Could you show the code which gives you errors when you try it?

Comment: I think I figured this out (and showed this in the attached link). The idea is that instead of a single concrete interface B you create a generic one, then use this generic one to create a template transformer connecting two formats - input one and output one - together.

Comment: Thanks raina, let me check and get back to you whether it solves my use case or not. Will keep you posted soon.